# How to configure Mule Properties Editor in Mule Studio

Tags: mule-studio

I have usecase that , i need to encrypt the values which are presented in properties file under src/main/resources.

Mule provided a concept called Mule Credentials Vault. In that document there is a place where we can open properties file in "Mule Properties  Editor" view.

Can you please let me out to get configured in my local mule studio.

Thanks.

Regards
Vikram

Comment: Hi All ,

Install the below plugin in mulestduio:

http://security-update-site.s3.amazonaws.com/

Updating for reference to others

Answer (score 2):

as per vikram you need to install the plugin first .you can look for the descripotion in below link

https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+Credentials+Vault

and also you can find the example application in below link

https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Anypoint+Enterprise+Security+Example+Application